# Dynamic vector of objects in java

Tags: java, loops, object, vector

how to create a vector of objects inside a loop, What I mean is, I want to create multiple objects inside a loop and store them in a vactor so I can access them and their methods later.

I know I can do this with Array or list, but I'd like to know how using vectors.

```
Vector<Class> test=new Vector<>();
for(i=0;i<xxx;i++){
    class obj = new Class();
    vector.add(obj(a,b,c,d))
}

for(i=0;i<xxx;i++){
    System.out.print(vector(i.getID));
}
```

something like this.

Comment: If you know how to loop then you shouldn't have an issue adding and element to the vector. Have you tried anything? If so what are you stuck on.

Comment: A Vector should be similar in usage to a `List` because it implements `List`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html

Comment: How can i create an object with each iteration,and add that object to vector, i should have said that i dont know how to use vector.

Comment: Then you find a tutorial on the web. This is off topic for stackoverflow.

Comment: Hint - As you said you know how to do it using list, just go ahead and write code using list and then just replace object type from `List` to `Vector`.

Comment: This is not off topic, i searched and didnt find what i want.
i just want to know how to add objects to vector inside a loop

Comment: @blackdedo93 Why you want to use only vector why not List? What type of objects you want to add to your vector? How many objects you want to add?

Comment: @Ravikumar in my assignment am not allowed to use array basically, and am not sure if i can use Vector as well to be honest, but since they're different then i think its okay. 
i have to ask the user for how many Staff the company has, thus i have no idea how many object i have to create, and thats why i have to put this in a loop to create object with different ID,Name,JobTitle.

Comment: @blackdedo93 Show us some code in order to help you?

Comment: @blackdedo93 did you look at the docs or do a simple search "java vector"? https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_vector_class.htm for instance gives you and overview of the object with sample code.

Comment: I'll check them out, in mean while, hope the code makes it easier for you guys to understand what i mean :)
and thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all my advice is start reading Java from first chapter.

Assume that you have a class called `User`.

```
import java.util.*;

public class User{
   // Two variables
   int id;
   String name;

   // Constructor to create Object of User with id and name
   public User(int id, String name){
     this.id = id;
     this.name = name;
   }

   // Getter methods to access id and name of a particular object
   public int getId(){
     return id;
   }

   public String getName(){
     return name;
   }

   // Main method to run
   public static void main(String[] args){
   // If you want to create 3 User object and store it in Vector, this is how it is done

     // This can be achieved even using list and array
     // List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
     // User[] userArray = new User[3];
     // For vector
     Vector<User> userVector = new vector<User>();
     for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
       User u = new User(i, "A" + i);
       userVector.add(u);
     }
     // To access user objects from Vector
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
       System.out.println("Id is " + userVector.get(i).getId() + " Name is " + userVector.get(i).getName());
     }
  }
}
```

Output -

1. Id is 0 Name is A0
2. Id is 1 Name is A1
3. Id is 2 Name is A2